# React Native Debugger state undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use the remote React Native Debugger for my project. I have installed React-Native-Debugger on my Mac with `$ brew update && brew cask install react-native-debugger`. Then I added Remote-redux-devtools package with `npm install --save-dev remote-redux-devtools`

My createStore code looks like this atm.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
/* some other imports */

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({ realtime: true, port: 8000 })
export default createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api), logger, firebaseSave)
))
```

Console output works just fine, but it is not picking up on the actions or redux state. Am I missing a step? Why isn't it picking up redux?

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Answer (score 6):

Here's the solution I used in order to make the redux states visible on the react-native-debugger:
Let's suppose That I have a redux reducer called `uiReducer`:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ui: uiReducer
});

let composeEnhancers = compose;

if (__DEV__) {
    composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)));
```

Please don't forget to import your reducer, and also the following imports from redux, react-redux and redux-thunk :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
```

Now, your state if visible in the debugger :

[image: debugger screenshot]

I hope it's helpful !
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Add redux devtools extension to your createStore

```
export default createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api), logger, firebaseSave)
),window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())
```

For more informations : https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension

Comment: I thought that package was not meant for React-Native?

Comment: See the documentation: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/redux-devtools-integration.md

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem where i thought the react native debugger is working fine,
E.g. 
react native debugger's mapper is working fine, it is pulling out my project file/directory at the source. 
Console output is working fine.

But i don't see any redux being picking up.

After some trials and errors, i found out i have to turn the JS Dev Mode on my android emulator.

Steps: Ctrl + M -> Dev Setting -> Check JS Dev Mode -> Reload

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that along with this, I couldn't see my sources in Developer tools which lead me to realise that I need to do this

On the IOS Simulator

Cmd + D > Debug JS Remotely worked for me